# Generalized Collatz sequences

Tags: nt.number-theory, collatz-conjecture

Let $\mathbb{N}$ denote the set of positive integers. For $k\in\mathbb{N}$ let $c_k:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ be defined by $x\mapsto x/2$ for $x$ even and $x\mapsto kx+1$ otherwise. The *Collatz sequence of $x\in \mathbb{N}$ with respect to $k$*, denoted by $\text{Coll}_{x,k}:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ is defined by $1\mapsto x$ and $n\mapsto c_k(\text{Coll}_{x,k}(n-1))$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}$.

The famous Collatz conjecture states that $$1\in\text{im(Coll}_{x,3})$$ for every $\in\mathbb{N}$.

For $k$ even, the behavior of $\text{Coll}_{x,k}$ is uninteresting, and it is easy to see that for every $x\in\mathbb{N}$, the sequence $\text{Coll}_{x,1}$ eventually periodic. Moreover, if $k>1$ and $k=4a+1$ for some $a\in\mathbb{N}$, we get that no member of $\text{im}(\text{Coll}_{k,k})$ is divisible by $4$ ... (**Edit:** apologies, this last statement is false as pointed out by user @wojowu! So I erroneously thought only $k=4a+1$ is uninteresting, so the questions below focus on $k=4a+3$.)

**Questions.**

1. Is there $a\in\mathbb{N}$ such that there is a positive integer $x$ such that $\text{Coll}_{x,4a+3}$ is unbounded? (The smallest known value of $a$ satisfying this would be of interest.)
2. Is there $a\in\mathbb{N}$ such that there is a positive integer $x$ such that $\text{Coll}_{x,4a+3}$ is bounded, but $1\notin \text{im}(\text{Coll}_{x,4a+3})$, or in other words, $\text{Coll}_{x,4a+3}$ is eventually periodic, but $1$ is not involved in the period?

**Edit.** I corrected the inductive definition of $\text{Coll}_{x,k}$. Thanks to user @wojowu for spotting my error.

Comment: I think the answer is negative because it was shown by [Terras](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=568274) that for almost all ${N}$ (in the sense of natural density), one has ${\mathrm{Col}_{\min}(N) < N}$ and this  was then improved by [Allouche](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=567874) and if there is a small a the investigation for it would be  beyond current tecknology

Comment: Note that $k=4a+1$ is not completely uninteresting.  For example, $k=5$ gets you the cycle 13,66,33,166,83,416,208,104,52,26,13, which does not contain 1.

Comment: Are you sure you mean $n\mapsto c_k(n-1)$ and not $n\mapsto c_k(Coll_{x,k}(n-1))$? Your claim about $k=4a+1$ is incorrect, since for $k=5$ the sequence starts with $5,26,13,66,33,166,83,416$ which is divisible by $4$.

Comment: See also [my question at Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1489225/127263). I don't think there are any known (provably) divergent trajectories in any of your sequences.

Comment: That's right @wojowu, will correct! And thanks everyone for the remarks for $n=5$

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen you have claimed in your first par of your question that the smallest known value of $a$ satisfying this would be of interest , could u pleas add some explanation about this point ?

Comment: I see you have corrected the definition but not the erroneous claim about $k=4a+1$. Do you happen to know if any of that claim is salvageable?

Comment: Right @wojowu, sorry for neglecting this. Will amend it.

Comment: @DominicvanderZypen, Why you didn't accept my answer if it convincing ?

Comment: Right, sorry, I missed it. Thanks for your answer and your effort!

Comment: Perhaps there is something with the wieferich prime $k=3511$ wich is $k \equiv 3 \pmod 4$. In R. Crandall's article of 1978 he discusses in short a specific property using the other wieferich prime $j=1093$ (but which is $j \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and thus uninteresting for your question). It seems he says, that necessarily there must be divergent trajectories (but I never got his idea and analysis properly, sorry). Because he uses the specific property of being "wieferich" it may extend as well to $j$ but which he didn't discuss. So - perhaps that might fit your question here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This long comment  might be helpful:

I think the answer is negative as I pointed out in the comments because almost all Collatz orbits attain almost bounded values, the result which is shown by [Terras](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=568274) and was proven by [Allouch](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=567874) which states that ${\mathrm{Col}_{\min}(N) < N}$ For almost all $N$ (in the sense of natural density), and there is an improvement [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2019/09/10/almost-all-collatz-orbits-attain-almost-bounded-values/) by Terry Tao in the sense of logarithmic density (**see Theorem 2**).