# 5n+1 sequence starting at 7

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, ds.dynamical-systems, sequences-and-series, open-problems

Consider the following variant of the Collatz function: $f:\mathbb N\rightarrow\mathbb N$ is defined by
\begin{equation}
 f(n):=\begin{cases}
      n/2 & \text{if $n$ is even}\\
      5n+1 & \text{if $n$ is odd}\\
\end{cases}  
\end{equation}
Contrary to the Collatz function with $3n+1$, many orbits of this function seem to diverge. The smallest one is probably 7. After 32282 iterations, $f^k(7)$ is already larger than $10^{1000}$. Can one prove that this orbit diverges to infinity?

Here is the Python code that I used:

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec=1001


def collatz5(n):
    if n%2 == 0:
        return Decimal(n)/Decimal(2)
    else:
        return Decimal(5)*Decimal(n)+Decimal(1)

n=7
for i in range(100000):
    if n>10**1000:
        print("bound exceeded")
        print("number of steps: ",i)
        break
    n=collatz5(n)
```

Comment: Just to clarify: the reason why one heuristically expects many orbits to diverge is because $5/2 = 2.5 > 2$ while in the Collatz case one has $3/2 = 1.5 < 2$.

Answer (score 9):

As far as I understand it, under the current state of things we cannot prove that any orbit of 5k+1 diverges. In fact, as far as I'm aware we cannot even prove that there exists an odd $a>1$ such that the function

\begin{equation}
 f(n):=\begin{cases}
      n/2 & \text{if $n$ is even}\\
      an+1 & \text{if $n$ is odd}\\
\end{cases}  
\end{equation}

contains a divergent orbit even though we suspect that these exists for any $a>3$. Edit: See comments below that we can almost but not fully prove this for $a=1093$.

Comment: For $a=1093$ R.Crandall in 1978 made a specific argument: *"The third  solvable case, $a  =  1093$,  is rather  peculiar.   In  this  problem,  a number
$n$  has  height  one  if  and  only  if  it  is  of  the  form $n  =  (2^{364p}   -  1)/1093 $ ; but,  as it  turns  out,  all other  $n$  have infinite  height.   This  follows  from  the  fact  that in  the  $1093 n +   1$  problem,  no  $n$  can  have  height  $2$,  since  Eq.  (7.2), with  $3$ replaced  by  $1093$,  $n  =  1$, and  $k$  set  equal  to  two,  is  easily  seen  to  be  impossible.*" (cntd...)

Comment: (...cntd) *"This  case is the  only  one  for  which  it  is known  that  almost  all  $n$  have  infinite  height."* So it seems, that for the Wieferich-prime $a=1093$ divergence has been proven, and I think the same argument should be valid for the second Wieferich-prime  $a=3511$ [R.E.Crandall, 1978, On  the  "3x + 1"  Problem]

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Thanks. Corrected.

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Interesting! Could you perhaps also tell what Crandall considers as the first two solvable cases? I'm curious.

Comment: @MaxMuller - that are the cycles for $a=5$ and $a=181$ *"The status  of  Conjecture  (8.1)  is  unsettled   for  most  of  the  remaining  "$ax  +  1$" problems.    It  is known  that  the  conjecture   is  true  for  $a  =  5,  181,$  and  $1093$;  but  all  other  cases  remain  elusive."* (pg 1291; I changed his variable $q$ to fit with $a$ here). (I could send you the pdf if you don't find it online.)

Comment: I see, thank you! I've found it - initially I thought it was a book (of which the contents are usually harder to find on the internet), but it's a paper (p. 11): https://www.jstor.org/stable/2006353

Comment: For a substantial extension of Crandall's observation, see this paper of Franco and  Pomerance:
https://math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/PDF/paper101.pdf
("On a conjecture of Crandall concerning the qx +1 problem")

Comment: I have looked at the papers linked and I don't think that they prove existence of infinite trajectory. Crandall shows that for $a=1093$ the trajectory cannot reach $1$ unless it gets there in one step, but that doesn't preclude existence of cycles, so unless I'm missing something, for all we know all such trajectories might eventually end in a cycle.

Comment: Yes, that's right: There's nothing in the Crandall work (or the extensions) about divergence to infinity --- just about failing to reach 1.

Comment: @Wojowu - ah, that's the point why I've always felt to have been trapped in that related arguments of R. Crandall, but didn't resolve (just recently in a comment to https://mathoverflow.net/q/372733/7710) . *"The trajectory cannot reach $1$"* - that's the focus there, nothing explicite about divergence or cycling. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I can't prove that an orbit diverges, but we would expect there to be many because the average growth factor is $\frac{1}{2}(\frac{5}{2})^{2-1} = 1.25>1$. This in contrast to the normal function where the growth factor is $\frac{1}{2}(\frac{3}{2})^{2-1} = 0.75<1$

A reasonable generalization and conjecture for the Collatz problem is:

$f_{pq}(n):= \begin{cases}
    n/p       & \quad \text{if } n \text{ is divisible by }p\\
    qn \text{ rounded up to the nearest multiple of }p  & \quad \text{if } n \text{ is not divisible by }p\\
  \end{cases}$

We can also express this function as (for ease of computation)

$
f_{pq}(n):=  \begin{cases}
    n/p       & \quad \text{if } n \text{ mod }p=0\\
    qn + p - (qn\text{ mod }p)  & \quad \text{otherwise}\\
  \end{cases}
$

Define the expected growth factor after $p$ iterations as $\frac{1}{p}(\frac{q}{p})^{p-1}$. I conjecture that when $p,q$ are relatively prime, $f_{pq}$ contains divergent orbits if and only if the expected growth factor is greater than 1.